# Initialization order of static readonly field

Tags: c#, static

I'm curious of the C# spec says anything about the order of initializing static field's in C# 5 (.net4).  For instance:

```
public class Test
{
   public static readonly string A = "hi";
   public static readonly string B = "bye";
   public static readonly string DEFAULT = A;
}
```

In testing (Mono 2.x) they seem to be initialized in the order they appear in code.  eg. As is, `DEFAULT` will have the value "hi", but if I move the definition for `DEFAULT` above A and B, it will be assigned `NULL` because A hasn't been assigned yet.

Is there a guarantee that the variables are initialized in order? Or is it up to the compiler?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is in the order that they appear in. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645758(v=vs.71).aspx).

> The static field variable initializers of a class correspond to a
>   sequence of assignments that are executed in the textual order in
>   which they appear in the class declaration.

Also, when you have a static constructor:

> If a static constructor (Section 10.11) exists in the class,
>   execution of the static field initializers occurs immediately prior to
>   executing that static constructor. Otherwise, the static field
>   initializers are executed at an implementation-dependent time prior to
>   the first use of a static field of that class.