# Declaration order of types or members in c#

Tags: c#, .net, constructor, static, program-entry-point

I am totally confused by some of the active discussions on declaration order of types or members in C#.

There is a trending question, what would be the output of this and why?

**Scenario 1:**

```
    class Program
    {

        static readonly int A = Method();
        static readonly int B = 42;
        static int Method() => B;

        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(A); // 0
        }
    }
```

and if suppose, I update the above code and make it something like this:

**Scenario 2:**

```
    class Program
    {

        
        static readonly int B = 42;
        static int Method() => B;
        static readonly int A = Method();
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(A); // 42
        }
    }
```

The output of `Scenario 1` is `0` against the output of `Scenario 2` is 42. How this output is zero or 42?

I have checked few answers but aren't able to understand, how and why these answers are 0 and 42.

[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564699/does-the-order-of-declaration-matter-in-java-c) [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062235/get-properties-in-order-of-declaration-using-reflection)

Comment: Don't you have something better to do? :D I would say, the field initializers are executed in the order as they are declared. In your samples are field initializers and static methods mixed. In scenario 1 field A will be initialized first with the return value of a static method returning B, which is not yet initialized. Scenario 2 is simple, field B gets initialized before field A gets its value form the static method returning B. And if someone could give me a tip how to make here a line-break instead of submitting the comment I would be realy happy ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the order of static class initialization in C# deterministic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681055/is-the-order-of-static-class-initialization-in-c-sharp-deterministic) and [Initialization order of static readonly field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230649/initialization-order-of-static-readonly-field) and [Static member initialization order within a single C# class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55368192/static-member-initialization-order-within-a-single-c-sharp-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write this:

```
class Program
{

    static readonly int A = Method();
    static readonly int B = 42;
    static int Method() => B;

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(A); // 0
    }
}
```

The compiler will generate a static constructor for you, which assigns the initial values to your various fields. The order of these assignments matches the order that the fields are declared in:

```
class Program
{

    static readonly int A;
    static readonly int B;

    static Program()
    {
        A = Method();
        B = 42;
    }

    static int Method() => B;

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(A); // 0
    }
}
```

When the static constructor runs, it's fairly clear that `Method()` is executed, and `A` assigned to, before `B` is assigned to. Fields have an initial value of 0, before anything is assigned to them. So `Method()` will return 0.

Follow the same logic for your second scenario, and you'll see how it's different.

Comment: Probably worth adding that the position of the method definition doesn't matter, it just exists (I just noticed that the author of the question changed the place of the `Method` in the second case)